# Didn't find class on path DixPathList

Tags: android, kotlin

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.recip.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.recip-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.recip-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

I am tried to resolve it.
I expect that I will find solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the class com.example.recip.SplashActivity was not found during application execution. Here are a few steps you can take to resolve this issue:

Rebuild the project:
Make sure your project is built correctly. Rebuild the project to ensure that all classes are compiled correctly and added to your APK.

Check the package name:
Make sure that your application package in code matches what is specified in the manifest. Check the AndroidManifest.xml file to ensure that the package in the  element matches the package used in the code.

Check the class name:
Make sure the SplashActivity class name is correct. Check the capitalization of letters and any typos.

Check the presence of the class in the code:
Make sure that the SplashActivity class actually exists in your project and is in the correct package. If not, create one.

Use the right libraries:
Check the dependencies in your project. Make sure all required libraries are added to the project and the correct versions are used.

Clean and rebuild the project:
Try cleaning the project and rebuilding it again. This can help avoid problems with cache and old files.

Check your Gradle settings:
Make sure your project's Gradle settings are correct. Check your build.gradle files to make sure the library versions and other settings are correct.

Check for extra libraries:
Sometimes problems can arise due to dependency conflicts. Check if there are any unnecessary or duplicate libraries in your project.

Use multithreaded execution (Multidex):
If your project is very large, try enabling multithreading support (Multidex) in Gradle. This can help avoid problems with limitations on the number of methods in dex files.

Update dependencies:
Make sure all dependencies in your project are updated to the latest versions.

```
<activity
android:name=".SplashActivity"
android:label="Splash Screen">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```